# How to check for wrong number of parameters passed to a function

Tags: javascript, typescript, tslint

I am writing a program using typescript and tslint as a linter.
My current favorite list of rules is the following (tslint.json):

```
{
    "extends": "tslint:recommended",

    "rules": {
        "comment-format": [false, "check-space"],
        "eofline": false,
        "triple-equals": [false, "allow-null-check"],
        "no-trailing-whitespace": false,
        "one-line": false,
        "no-empty": false,
        "typedef-whitespace": false,
        "whitespace": false,
        "radix": false,
        "no-consecutive-blank-lines": false,
        "no-console": false,
        "typedef": [true,
            "variable-declaration",
            "call-signature",
            "parameter",
            "property-declaration",
            "member-variable-declaration"
        ],
        "quotemark": false,
        "no-any": true,
        "one-variable-per-declaration": false
    }

}
```

Although I am using Tslint it fails to catch a calling to a function with wrong number of parameters.
For example I have the following function :

```
let displayTimer: Function = function(): void {
    document.getElementById('milliseconds').innerHTML = ms.toString();
    document.getElementById('seconds').innerHTML = seconds.toString();
    document.getElementById('minutes').innerHTML= minutes.toString();
};
```

And I am calling it with from inside another function like this :

```
let turnTimerOn: Function = function(): void {

    ms += interval;

    if (ms >= 1000)
    {
        ms = 0;
        seconds += 1;
    }

    if (seconds >= 60)
    {
        ms = 0;
        seconds = 0;
        minutes += 1;
    }

    displayTimer(1);
};
```

As you can see I am passing a parameter to the displayTimer function (in this case the number 1 but it could be anything else) and the linter is not catching that.

Comment: well, that's because it's not invalid javascript. it is perfectly valid to pass values you have not defined as parameters and later retrieve them in the function using the **arguments**.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out.I am coming from a Java/C# background so I want to be able to check for this type of mismatch.Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but is there a reason the function is not declared as `function displayTimer():void {`? I think TS would better be able to check that. Right now all it's working off of for typing is `let displayTimer:Function = ???`. It doesn't know whether at some point you'll reassign null or some other function to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remove the type `Function` and TypeScript will check the signature:

```
let displayTimer = function(): void {
    // ...
};

displayTimer(1); // Error: Supplied parameters does not match any signature of call target
```

The inferred type of `displayTimer` is not `Function` (which accepts any signatures) but `() => void`.

See [the code in the PlayGround](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=let%20displayTimer%3A%20%28%29%20%3D%3E%20void%20%3D%20function%28%29%3A%20void%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20...%0A%7D%3B%0AdisplayTimer%281%29%3B).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.You were right about typescript compiler that detects the error when I remove the Function type declaration.The problem is that with these tslint rules as soon as I remove the declaration I see that tslint complains about this removal (TSLint: expected variable declaration: 'displayTimer' to have a typedef (typedef))

Comment: Following your suggestion I've used the following code to declare and assign a value in the same line.It is a little ugly but it works: `let displayTimer: () => void = function(): void{
    document.getElementById('milliseconds').innerHTML = ms.toString();
    document.getElementById('seconds').innerHTML = seconds.toString();
    document.getElementById('minutes').innerHTML= minutes.toString();
};`

Comment: @skiabox IMO, you should use inference where it can be used. `let displayTimer: () => void = function(): void { /* ... */ }` is not DRY.

Comment: Can you explain the term DRY please?Thank you!

Comment: @skiabox [Don't repeat yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). Maybe you should consider the compilation option `noImplicitAny` of the TS compiler ([see compilation options here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)).